# Normal extension and algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $L/F$ be an algebraic normal extension, every embedding of $L\rightarrow \overline{F}$ induces an automorphism of $L$. We know that the algebraic clousure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of all algebraic numbers $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. My question is, why in so many algebra book or number theory book, the writer wrote "When $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, i.e. when all the isomorphisms of $F$ into $\mathbb{C}$ are actually automorphisms." (this is quoted from ireland and rosen's number theory book). Shouldn't $\mathbb{C}$ be replaced by $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be exactly the same. An embedding of $F$ into $\mathbb{C}$ must necessarily lie in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, since $F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I think often authors prefer to use $\mathbb{C}$ because it's a better known object that people are just more comfortable with and can think about more concretely. On the other hand, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ seems more abstract - I sort of think of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ as lying inside $\mathbb{C}$ as a dense (totally disconnected?) subset.